# Javascript Promise().then to prevent re-calling the function before the first call be executed

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, server-sent-events, es6-promise

In my node.js app, reading data from MSSQL using tedious, I'm calling the below every 1 second:

1. Fetch the data from the server (`fetchStock` function) and save it in temporary array
2. Send the data saved in the temporary array to the client using the Server-Sent Events (SSE) API.

It looks the 1 second is not enough to recall the `fetchStock` function before the previous call is completely executed, so I get execution errors from time to time.
I increased it to 5 seconds, but still get the same issue every once in a while.

How can I use `Promise().then` to be sure the `fetchStock`  function is not re-called before the previouse call be completely executed?

```
var Request = require('tedious').Request;
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var config = {
     userName: 'sa',
     password: 'pswd',
    server: 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx',
    options: {
        database: 'DB',
             rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: 'true',
             rowCollectionOnDone: 'true'
     },
 };
var sql = new Connection(config);

var addElem = (obj, elem)=> [].push.call(obj, elem);
var result = {}, tmpCol = {}, tmpRow = {};
module.exports = {

  displayStock: function (es) {
      var dloop = setInterval(function() {
      if(result.error !== null)
            if (es) es.send(JSON.stringify(result), {event: 'rmSoH', id: (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()});
      if(result.error === null)
            if (es) es.send('connection is closed');
      }, 1000);
  },

  fetchStock: function () {
            request = new Request("SELECT ItemCode, WhsCode, OnHand FROM OITW where OnHand > 0 and (WhsCode ='RM' or WhsCode ='FG');", function(err, rowCount, rows) {
            if (err) {
            result = {'error': err};
            console.log((new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()+' err : '+err);
             }
             if(rows)
             rows.forEach(function(row){
                 row.forEach(function(column){
                     var colName = column.metadata.colName;
                     var value = column.value;
                     addElem(tmpCol, {colName: value})
                 });
             addElem(tmpRow,{'item': tmpCol[0].colName, 'Whs': tmpCol[1].colName, 'Qty': tmpCol[2].colName});
             tmpCol = {};
           });
           result = tmpRow;
           tmpRow={}
       });
    sql.execSql(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use a promise for this task?

Comment: Not necessary to use promise, I thought promise could help, what I need is just to prevent the fetchStock function from being re-run before the previous run be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is a simple variable to check if there's already running request not `Promise`.

```
var latch = false;
// It will be called only if the previous call is completed
var doFetchStock = () => sql.execSql(new Request("SQL", (err, rowCount, rows) => {
  // Your logic dealing with result

  // Initializes the latch
  latch = false;
});
module.exports = {
  fetchStock: function () {
    // Check if the previous request is completed or not
    if (!latch) {
      // Sets the latch
      latch = true;
      // Fetches stock
      doFetchStock();
    }
  }
};
```

Actually I've used this kind of pattern a lot to allow some behavior only once.

- https://github.com/cettia/cettia-javascript-client/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/cettia.js#L397-L413
- https://github.com/cettia/cettia-javascript-client/blob/1.0.0-Beta1/cettia.js#L775-L797

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript is mono-threaded a simple code like this should be enough on client-side

```
function () {
       if(currentPromise != null){ // define in a closure outside
            currentPromise = [..] // call to server which return a promise
            currentPromise.then(function(){
                currentPromise = null;
            });
       }
}
```

Comment: Did not get it, every thing here is done in the server side, and server is sending the data to the client(s) through SSE, so client has nothing to do here.

Comment: So you want to block all client requests as long as one stock fetching is running ? Javascriptis mono-threaded in server side too, so you can use a trick like i did. However i don't know how to have variable shared to different requests.

Comment: Forget the clients,  just need the server not to re-run it, before before the first one completed.

Comment: As i said in my comment, if you can persist variable in memory to be avalable for others request, just use a boolean, there is no concurrency at the moment in server-side js.